# How to create an utf8 file from stringbuilder object in Java

Tags: java, file, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages

I have a problem with file encoding. I have a method which exports my DB to a XML in a format I created. The problem is that the file is created with **ANSI encoding** and I need **UTF-8 encoding** (some spanish characters aren't shown propperly on ANSI).

The XML file is generated from a **StringBuilder** object: I write the data from my DB to this StringBuilder object and when I have copied all the data I create the file.

Any help is gratefully received. Thanks in advace.

Edit: This is part of my source:
**XMLBuilder class:**

```
...
    public XmlBuilder() throws IOException {
      this.sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
...
    public String xmlBuild() throws IOException{
      this.sb.append(CLOSE_DB);
      return this.sb.toString();
    }
...
```

**Service class where I generate the XML file:**

```
XmlBuilder xml = new XmlBuilder();
... (adding to xml)...
xmlString = xml.build();
file = createXml(xmlString);
...
```

**createXml**:

```
public File createXml(String textToFile) {
  File folder = new File("xml/exported/");
  if (!folder.exists()) {
      folder.mkdirs();
  }
  file = new File("xml/exported/exportedData.xml");

  try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    //if file exists, then delete it and create it
    else {
        file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    // get the content in bytes
    byte[] contentInBytes = textToFile.getBytes();

    fop.write(contentInBytes);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return file;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you write your file? Usually you can provide an encoding as an extra parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Keppil. I have just edited my question with source code.

Comment: Try @Keith's answer below, I think it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    File file = new File("file.xml");
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8");
    writer.write("<file content>");
    writer.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Keith. I will try it tomorrow. If it works I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Hi @Keith. I have just tried it but file encoding is still detected as "ANSI as UTF-8", but all the characters are shown properly now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could try explicitly writing the BoM, `\uFEFF` at the start of the file.  That might help other programs identify the correct encoding.